# Use gulp task for multiple builds

Tags: javascript, build, gulp, build-process

**Question**

When running a gulp task, is it possible to run the task twice on different files, outputting to different destinations?

**Source to destination example:**

`/assets/frontend/src/js/app.js` >> `/assets/frontend/dist/js/app.min.js`

and also:

`/assets/admin/src/js/app.js` >> `/assets/admin/dist/js/app.min.js`

**Code example:**

```
gulp.task('javascript', function() {
    return gulp.src(['/assets/frontend/src/js/app.js', '/assets/admin/src/js/app.js'])
      .pipe(some_task_thingy()) 
      .pipe(gulp.dest(['/assets/frontend/dist/js/app.min.js', '/assets/admin/dist/js/app.min.js']);  
});
```

**Why?**

I don't want to serve files to users who do not need them. AKA users that will not log into admin area.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: When running a gulp task is it possible to run the task twice on different files, outputting to different destinations.

Comment: You want to execute the same `task` on two different files and output them in two different folders?

Comment: I use `another task` to do this. One task for `frontendtask` one task for `backendtask` and one task for both: `gulp.task('both', ['frontendtask', 'backendtask']);`

Comment: Although they will be exactly the same, i feel that is very code redundant.